# SQL Server - CTE causing 'multi-part identifier could not be bound'

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, identifier

I am trying to return the previous values of rows.  Before this, I was using lag/lead, but I am looking to improve the performance.  Anywho, I get the error about the multi-part identifier could not be bound on the [dbo].[Backfill].[RowNum] part.  I've looked at other similar questions here on S.O., but couldn't resolve my issue.

```
WITH updated
AS (
SELECT g.[RowNum] AS 'RowNum'
    ,g.[Meter#] AS 'PrevMeter#'
    ,g.[StartDate] AS 'PrevStartDate'
    ,g.[EndDate] AS 'PrevEndDate'
    ,g.[UsageAmt] AS 'PrevUsageAmt'
    ,g.[ReadingType] AS 'PrevReadType'
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM [dbo].[Backfill] z
    WHERE z.RowNum < [dbo].[Backfill].[RowNum]
    ORDER BY rownum DESC
    ) AS g
)
```

However, if I run

```
WITH updated AS
(

SELECT  [RowNum],           
        (SELECT [Meter#] FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.backfill z WHERE z.rownum < dbo.backfill.rownum ORDER BY rownum DESC) AS g) AS 'PrevMeter#',
        (SELECT [StartDate] FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.backfill z WHERE z.rownum < dbo.backfill.rownum ORDER BY rownum DESC) AS g) AS 'PrevStartDate',
        (SELECT [EndDate] FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.backfill z WHERE z.rownum < dbo.backfill.rownum ORDER BY rownum DESC) AS g) AS 'PrevEndDate',   
        (SELECT [UsageAmt] FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.backfill z WHERE z.rownum < dbo.backfill.rownum ORDER BY rownum DESC) AS g) AS 'PrevUsageAmt',     
        (SELECT [ReadingType] FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.backfill z WHERE z.rownum < dbo.backfill.rownum ORDER BY rownum DESC) AS g) AS 'PrevReadType'       

FROM dbo.backfill
)
```

It works just fine.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you've got to work out your RowNum haven't you?  Unless it's something I don't know about - see Row_Number() in MS SQL

Comment: Logically your query will never return any rows because you have a where clause that only returns a row where RowNum < RowNum which is not possible. Also, you really don't to use a subquery in your cte unless you meant to use ROW_NUMBER and forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to join back to the same table? If so you're missing the join.

```
WITH updated
AS (
SELECT g.[RowNum] AS 'RowNum'
    ,g.[Meter#] AS 'PrevMeter#'
    ,g.[StartDate] AS 'PrevStartDate'
    ,g.[EndDate] AS 'PrevEndDate'
    ,g.[UsageAmt] AS 'PrevUsageAmt'
    ,g.[ReadingType] AS 'PrevReadType'
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 z.*
    FROM [dbo].[Backfill] z
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Backfill] x ON z.? = x.?
    WHERE z.RowNum < x.[RowNum]
    ORDER BY z.rownum DESC
    ) AS g
)
```

Comment: damnit, it was so simple, lol.  But now I get an error, "the column 'RowNum' was specified multiple times for g."

Comment: Try replacing the `*` with explicitly named columns.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example you use

```
SELECT [RowNum],
       sub-select
FROM dbo.backfill
```

This last `FROM` is missing in your first example...

It might be something like this, what you are looking for:

```
WITH updated AS
(

SELECT  [RowNum]
       ,g.* 
FROM dbo.backfill
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [Meter#] AS [PrevMeter#]
                        ,[StartDate] AS PrevStartDate
                        ,[EndDate] AS PrevEndDate
                        ,[UsageAmt] AS PrevUsageAmt
                        ,[ReadingType] AS PrevReadingType
            FROM dbo.backfill AS z 
            WHERE z.RowNum < dbo.backfill.RowNum 
            ORDER BY z.RowNum DESC) AS g
)
SELECT * FROM updated
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first query SQL cannot find `[dbo].[Backfill].[RowNum]` because there is no join to this table. Try:

```
;WITH updated
AS (
SELECT b.[RowNum] AS 'RowNum'
    ,g.[Meter#] AS 'PrevMeter#'
    ,g.[StartDate] AS 'PrevStartDate'
    ,g.[EndDate] AS 'PrevEndDate'
    ,g.[UsageAmt] AS 'PrevUsageAmt'
    ,g.[ReadingType] AS 'PrevReadType'
FROM [dbo].[Backfill] b
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM [dbo].[Backfill]
    WHERE RowNum < b.[RowNum]
    ORDER BY RowNum DESC
    ) AS g
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT z.*, TheLead.*, TheLag.*
FROM [dbo].[Backfill] z
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Backfill] TheLead ON TheLead.RowNum - 1 = z.RowNum
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Backfill] TheLag  ON TheLag.RowNum + 1 = z.RowNum
WHERE z.RowNum < [dbo].[Backfill].[RowNum]
```